# Unix/Linux extract remaining available space on mount point from df output

Tags: linux, perl, unix, awk

I am writing a script (perl) and I would like to get remaining KB on some mount point. Command df -k return more information than I need.

```
~  df -k /var
Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/vx/dsk/bootdg/var
                 8267957 5749576 **2435702**    71%    /var
```

Is there some way to cut result with AWK, to get just available space. But it give me same result I run it on Linux or Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Perl:

```
my %df = map { $_ = [ split ]; $_->[-1] => $_ } `df -P`;

print "Free space for /var: $df{'/var'}[3]\n";
```

[`man df`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?df):

> ```
>   -P, --portability
>           use the POSIX output format
> ```

Comment: Is there some way to instead of value '/var' we use some perl variable as hash key?

Comment: @user3292147 try it, `$df{$somevar}[3]`

Answer (score 0):

Try : 
df -h | awk '{print $4}'  //$4 should be free file I think, you can change the variable according to your requirements